# Google App Engine MySQL Error 1064: Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine

I'm trying to run this query but it's not working in Google App Engine(MySQL 2nd Gen. v5.7). It's showing me an syntax error. I don't understand why it's not working because in PHPMyAdmin(Mysql v5.7) everything is OK.

This is my query:

```
SET @row_num := 0;
SELECT row_number
FROM (SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_number, id FROM users ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, ?) result
WHERE result.id = ? LIMIT 1
```

error:

`Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT row_number
        FROM (SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_number, id FROM' at line 2`

Comment: Hi, I am trying to understand your inner SELECT query. After LIMIT 0 you have a comma and question mark just before the closing parenthesis. What is this for?

Comment: @J2112O prepared statements, 0 is offset. I already tried `ÒRDER BY id ASC LIMIT ?`. same thing